# Click event NOT firing on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios

The click event can't be fired on iOS for first time.

Anyway it can work well when I remove `document.body.appendChild(p)`.

It seems a iOS bug? Somebody can help me? Thanks.

```
<label id="handler" style="cursor: pointer;">Click Me</label>

<script>
    var handler = document.getElementById('handler');

    handler.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    });

    handler.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert('Clicked');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You may want to add a `mouseout` that removes the `<p>` elements you are adding, with the code you've supplied, you'll add a `<p>` everytime you `mouseover`.

Comment: it still doesn't work.